# Intellij IDEA Freezes when clicking on "Open" in macOS

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, macos-catalina

I've recently installed the IDEA on my machine but when I open that and try clicking on "Open" to open a project the IDEA Freezes and I only exit this situation by killing the process. I've searched on the web for some solutions however I haven't found anyone solution or report similar. Can anyone help me?

[image]

Intellij IDEA Version: 2021.2.3

macOS Catalina - Version 10.15.7

Answer (score 3):

Issue should be fixed in 2021.3 version. For now, please try the following workaround:

- Open the IDE Registry (search for action → type Registry)
- Turn off the flag `awt.file.dialog.enable.filter`

Comment: @augusto, did you try, is this the answer?

Comment: To open IDE register in MacOS, press on Command-Alt-Shift-/ and select "Registry" (Credit to https://newbedev.com/how-do-you-set-a-value-in-the-intellij-registry)

Comment: Tried this on PhpStorm 2023.1.3. Didn't work.